# OpenSAML v3 - Validate SAML Response

Tags: saml-2.0, opensaml

We are implementing Service provider for IDP initiated SSO. We are using open `SAML v3` `java library` to parse the SAML response using POST.

I want to validate the SAML data and format, so trying to figure out is there any inbuilt methods which I can make use to validate the SAML data. 
I am able to validate the signature using SAMLSignatureProfileValidator and SignatureValidator but I also want to validate that SAML version, the entity provider,Audience, conditions and so on.

When I dive deep into the library I was able to find that the class `WSSecuritySAML20AssertionTokenSecurityHandler` which validate `SAML` when doInvoke() method is called but the message Should SOAP. This method uses SAML20AssertionValidator to validate.

I am planning to use SAML20AssertionValidator to validate the Assertion so I need help to instaniate the SAML20AssertionValidator. The constructor for SAML20AssertionValidator is as follows. Trying to understand the input parameters

```
public SAML20AssertionValidator(@Nullable final Collection<ConditionValidator> newConditionValidators,
        @Nullable final Collection<SubjectConfirmationValidator> newConfirmationValidators,
        @Nullable Collection<StatementValidator> newStatementValidators, 
        @Nullable final SignatureTrustEngine newTrustEngine,
        @Nullable final SignaturePrevalidator newSignaturePrevalidator) {
```

Also want to make sure is this the right direction to go for validation or is there any other methods I can make use of?

Any directions on this is much appreciated.